# VM virtualbox - shouldn't I remove VBoxGuestAdditions.iso?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image

I have set a windows 10 OS in Oracle VM virtualbox, about not being full screen issue, I have downloaded and installed Guest Additions, now I can make it full screen.

My question is, because I am done with it, I want to remove the `.iso` from the virtual disk, however, it displays a warning, which I don't relate to the situation.

So, I want to know if it is something I should not do or not.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just eject the disk from within the OS?  The prompt is asking if you would like to remove the virtual optical drive, which you could do, but then you couldn't mount different ISOs within the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

You're a not ejecting the virtual CD (the ISO) from the virtual optical drive, but your are removing the entire optical drive itself from the virtual machine.
If that is what you intended to do, fine, but most people do that by accident and that is why VirtualBox gives that warning.

Comment: The option to remove the ISO, from the virtual drive, is the icon next to the drop down box.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes it is. I couldn't really see that clearly earlier when I answered while on my phone. Or you can use the regular Eject from within the guest OS. Or you use the Eject from the VirtualBox menu while the VM runs.